# What's the update equivalent of insertMany in Mongo / Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to do a bulk upsert, but am having problems to figure out how to do it. This does not work:

```
    BasicDBObject filter = new BasicDBObject();
    BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject("$set", list);
    UpdateOptions options = new UpdateOptions().upsert(true);
    collection.updateMany(filter, update, options);
```

Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: Modifiers operate on fields but we found a Array instead.

Any examples would just be great!

### UpsertMany items in one roundtrip

This is what I meant:

```
public static BulkWriteResult upsertAll(MongoCollection<Document> coll, List<Document> docs, String keyTag) {
    List<UpdateOneModel<Document>> requests = new ArrayList<UpdateOneModel<Document>>();
    UpdateOptions opt = new UpdateOptions().upsert(true);
    for (Document doc : docs ) {
        BasicDBObject filter = new BasicDBObject(keyTag, doc.get(keyTag)); 
        BasicDBObject action = new BasicDBObject("$set", doc);
        requests.add(new UpdateOneModel<Document>(filter, action, opt));
    }
    return coll.bulkWrite(requests);
}
```

Comment: Aaah! I guess it won't work because the filter selects all elements in collection that need to be updated with ONE new version of the document... What I intend to do is just a bulk upsert, but in case the corresponding item (unique index) does exist, it should be overwritten.

Comment: The error is really about the syntax of your update - it looks like you are making a DBObject like `{ "$set" : [1, 2, 3] }` instead of `{ "$set" : { "my_field" : [1, 2, 3] } }`.

Comment: I am. And that is because I intend to insert many objects in the collection, instead of updating many objects with one new value. So, my guess is, it can't be done. Alternatively I could do a bulk insert and then check if there were errors (duplicates), and update these. Am I right?

Comment: So something like this:   
 
  try {
   collection.insertMany(list);
  } catch (MongoBulkWriteException e) {
   for ( BulkWriteError i : e.getWriteErrors() ) {
    Document d = list.get(i.getIndex());
    collection.insertOne(d);
   }
  }

Comment: Which java driver are you using? I did not find collection.updateMany() method in 2.13 and 3.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform bulk upsert using below code :

```
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    DB db = (DB) mongo.getDB("testDB");
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("collection");

    BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject();
    obj.append("$set", new BasicDBObject("my_field", dbList));

    BasicDBList dbList = new BasicDBList();
    dbList.add(1);
    dbList.add(2);
    dbList.add(3);

    BulkWriteOperation bwo = collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOperation();
    bwo.find(new BasicDBObject()).upsert().update(obj);
    bwo.execute();
```

For more details you can check : http://www.journaldev.com/6324/mongodb-upsert-example-using-mongo-shell-and-java-driver

Answer (score -1):

This might work

db.collection.update({},{$set : {"my_field":[1, 2, 3]}},false,true)